# Can ssh into but not out of new server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssh

I just setup a new Ubuntu 16.04 remote server.

I can ssh into it fine. I can rsync and other things I have tried fine.

I cannot, however, seem to ssh out... Thats is, something like:

```
ssh user@otherhost
```

Just hangs and eventually throws the error:

```
ssh: connect to host otherhost port 22: Connection timed out
```

What would cause this?

I have tried ssh'ing to and from my other servers; All of them are accepting and sending SSH from each other. The issue seems to only happen with this speciific server...

openssh-server and openssh-client are installed.

Comment: Maybe a firewall is blocking outbound packets to port 22.

Comment: Double check port, try to use the ip instead of the hostname.

Comment: To add to the above, check your hosts file to make sure you don't have an old ip in there against that hostname

Comment: Ok, seems my VPS provider was blocking the outbound port.